# javascript search() working problem

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an jquery autosuggest plugin in which when i type ex. `Korea` then it show 2 results i.e.
`Korea (North)` & `Korea (South)` but when i type `Korea (`, its not displaying any result where it had to show both `Korea (North)` & `Korea (South)`.

After searching in the code for the error then i found a `search()` function which search for the type string in the results..

means:
`Korea (` in `Korea (North)` & `Korea (South)`

and i think this search function stops at bracket `(` and i don't know why???

Please, suggest a search() function to remove this error..

code:::

```
str.search(query) != -1
```

where: str = one result at a time i.e. `Korea (North)`
       query = entered string i.e. `Korea (`

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `search()` is treated a regular expression, and `Korea (` is an invalid regular expression. This is why `"Korea (North)".search("Korea (")` fails.

Use `indexOf()` instead:

```
str.indexOf(query) != -1
```

Comment: its not working..
as when i output the result using:

`console.log(str.substr(0, query.length)+' '+query);` = `kore orea`
where query is the enterd string i.e. `orea`

now its not working overall.

Comment: then use `str.indexOf(query) != -1` :-)

Comment: @user576875: and what about this:
`var regx = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + query + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi")`

Comment: this will have the exact same problem. You need to escape he query variable if you embed it in a RegExp. Use str.indexOf() :-)

Answer (score 0):

search() is a regular expression function. The ( character has significant meaning in regular expression, hence why the search fails. If you escape the ( with a backslash it should work

```
str.search("Korea \(");
```

Comment: thx.. but i had this string in a variable named: `query`...
like: `str.search(query);` where query is `Korea (`

Comment: You could use replace() to escape the query. query.replace(/[\\(\\)]/, "/\\1")

Comment: I haven't tested the above code and I'm not 100% sure of the replace() syntax but you should be able to find good documentation by Googleing "mdc replace"